# Unity IoC static class to access resolved concrete class for S3 image retrieval

Tags: amazon-s3, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am writing a static class that will allow me to resolve a file name which I am storing on S3.

I want it as a static class so I can globally use it but I want to to be backed by an IStorage interface so I can switch out the concrete class easily. The problem I am having is with static classes not working with Unity - this of course makes sense but I really dont want to start mixing DI code within my static class. I have read about using a delegate wrapper but I am a little confused as to how this could work, as the DI would only be resolving the concrete and therefore where does the static class come in to play? Here is what I have so far

```
public static class StorageStatic
{
    public static string GetFileName(string filename)
    {
        //This needs to resolve to the correct concrete class, but cannot get the instance of it.
        return filename;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to inject dependencies into the class using Unity then the class can't be static -- you will need an instance to inject into.  You could make StorageStatic a singleton if that is required.

Comment: @RandyLevy I dont mind making it a singleton but I am still confused on where and how I need to declare this. Do you have any links or code that may help?